# PLS-00306 when calling Oracle stored procedure in Node.js

Tags: node.js, oracle, plsql, node-oracledb

how to solve " ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_TICKER_INFO' ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored "?

Hi, I am new in node and Oracle.
Not able to run the procedure using node js. need help to solve this
Oracle procedure reference

```
PROCEDURE get_data_info (
  p_ticker       VARCHAR2,
  p_acronym      VARCHAR2,
  p_sort         VARCHAR2,
  p_call_source  VARCHAR2,
  p_data     OUT REF_CRS);
```

Node js code

```
sql = 'begin get_data_info(:p_ticker,:p_acronym,:p_sort,:p_call_source,:p_data); end;';
        // run procedure to get all data
        const ticker_data ={
          p_ticker: '',
          p_acronym: '',
          p_sort: '',
          p_call_source: '',
          p_data: ''
        };
        data = { p_ticker: 'AAPL', p_data: ':output'};
        binds  = Object.assign({}, ticker_data, data);
        
        options = {
            outFormat: oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT,  
        };
        result = await connection.execute(sql, binds, options);
```

Comment: the p_data     OUT REF_CRS , what is REF_CRS ? is a type you have ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guessing that `REF_CRS` is a REF CURSOR, your problem is the definition of `p_data` in the bind parameter object.  You need to give it a type and direction like:

```
p_data: {dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.CURSOR}
```

Check the node-oracledb documentation chapter [REF CURSOR Bind Parameters](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#refcursors).

Working code would be like:

```
/*

create or replace PROCEDURE get_data_info (
  p_ticker       VARCHAR2,
  p_acronym      VARCHAR2,
  p_sort         VARCHAR2,
  p_call_source  VARCHAR2,
  p_data     OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) as
begin
  open p_data for select * from dual;
end;
/
show errors

*/

const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const dbConfig = { user: 'cj', password: 'cj', connectString: 'localhost/orclpdb1' };

if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
  oracledb.initOracleClient({libDir: '/Users/cjones/instantclient_19_3'});
}

let sql, binds, options, result;
sql = `SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_DATE, 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH24:MI') AS D FROM DUAL`;
options = {
//  outFormat: oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT  // uncomment if you want object output instead of array
};

async function run() {
  let connection;
  
  try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);
    
    sql = 'begin get_data_info(:p_ticker,:p_acronym,:p_sort,:p_call_source,:p_data); end;';
    
    const ticker_data = {
      p_ticker: '',
      p_acronym: '',
      p_sort: '',
      p_call_source: '',
      p_data: ''
    };
    const data = { p_ticker: 'AAPL', p_data: {dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.CURSOR}};
    const binds  = Object.assign({}, ticker_data, data);   

    result = await connection.execute(sql, binds, options);

    const resultSet = result.outBinds.p_data;
    let row;
    while ((row = await resultSet.getRow())) {
      console.log(row);
    }
    await resultSet.close();   // always close the ResultSet
    
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      try {
    await connection.close();
      } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}

run();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. it's working, but in the result set, the attribute name was missing. How we can fix this.

Comment: If you mean column names and type info, then look at the [metadata](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#rsmetadata).

Comment: If you mean you want objects instead of arrays, check the `options` variable I updated my answer with.